# Armazenar valor de uma função em um scaffold

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Eu possuo um código em Rails com um input que carrega arquivos e um botão que coleta o nome do arquivo selecionado através do input:

```
<label id="myLabel" for="file"></label>
<%= file_field_tag 'file' %>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Salvar nome do arquivo</button>
```

Sim eu misturei Html com código Ruby, mas eu não sei como é um label em código Ruby.

Esse é meu código JS, mas só a parte da coleta do nome, que é a que importa no momento:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('file').files[0].name; 
  alert(x);
}
```

Como eu poderia pegar o valor dessa função e armazena-la em meu scaffold?

Meu scaffold (que eu gostaria de armazena-lo):

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Histórico</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Arquivos validados:</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @historicos.each do |historico| %>
      <tr>
        ##ss<td><%= link_to 'Show', historico %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= link_to 'Voltar', root_path %>
<br>
```

Sim, eu removi a box para digitar os textos até por que os nomes seriam obtidos através da minha função então eu não via motivo de possui-los eu tbm removi os links para as outras views(show, delete e edit).

Agradeço desde já!!!

Answer (score 0):

Quando você diz que quer salvar no seu scaffold, você quer dizer no banco de dados? Ou apenas exibir na página onde o arquivo é selecionado?

Se for para exibição, você pode usar Javascript para atribuir o resultado de `document.getElementById('file').files[0].name;` em algum elemento do DOM. Dá para fazer isso dentro dessa função que você criou:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fileName = document.getElementById('file').files[0].name;
  document.getElementById('#file-name').value = fileName;
}
```

Se for para salvar no banco de dados, supondo que o file_field_tag esteja dentro de um form, você tem acesso aos dados do arquivo no controller. Nesse caso, sua página feita via scaffold teria acesso ao dado direto da instância `historico`.

Os dois códigos estão em páginas diferentes?